# Angular http call : Code inside subscribe doesn't trigger

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have written two identical https calls, with identical backend POST methods written in C# but for some reason one of the two calls doesn't trigger the code inside the `subscribe`  method.

Here is the method that doesnt work :

```
     var body = {'fileName' : GlobalConstants.SELECTED_CONTENTS[0].name, 'campaignMessage' : GlobalConstants.CAMPAIGNS[0].message}
      this.http.post(GlobalConstants.baseURL + "sendtweet", body).subscribe((res : any) => {
        console.log("tweet has been posted!")
      this.toast.success("Successfully posted to twitter");
      
      })
```

The backend code for this call :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/sendtweet")]
        public async Task<string> SendTweet()
        {
            string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            string fileName = (string)data["fileName"].ToObject(typeof(string));
         
            var appCredentials = new TwitterCredentials(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);

            var client = new TwitterClient(appCredentials);
            await TweetWithMedia(client, fileName);
            return result;
        }
```

In the same application, I have another http call that does work, here is the angular side code for that :

```
this.http.post(GlobalConstants.baseURL + "UploadToVideos", GlobalConstants.SELECTED_CONTENTS[0].name).subscribe((res : any) => {
        console.log("published successfully")
      })
```

Here is the backend code for this :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/ConvertToGif")]
        public async Task<string> ConvertToGif()
        {
            string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

            string fileName = (string)data["fileName"].ToObject(typeof(string));

            ConvertMP42Gif(fileName);
            ConvertMP42GifTwitter(fileName);

            return result;
        }
```

I don't see any difference in code structure, return types or even the call format. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: I just wanted to show there's no difference of return type either

Comment: On angular side pass HTTP Params Content-Type: 'application/json'. Might be it's work for you.

Comment: Do you place a breakpoint on the API side to see whether the API action is hit and returns a response? While also checking the browser DevTools Network tab to see whether the response is returned. If the response is returned, show us what is the response received. Is it status 200 OK or other status? Possibly you mention the inner subscribe was not triggered as the returned response is not with a success status, and your current observer only handles success callback.

Comment: The API call is definitely hit, because it completes the action defined in the API call. however, I dont see any response at all in the network tab in dev tools. The headers and Payload sections are as expected but the response is blank. In the timing section I see ```CAUTION : request is not finished yet!```